# Update element's text when $emit function has been triggered

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, emit

In vue, would it be possible to update element text when $emit function has been triggered inside the element?

Here is a code snippet:

```
<a href="#" @click="fire('openCrudRoleModal',{{$role}})"
 @updateRoleName="change text in this <a>">{{$role->name}}</a>
```

Within Laravel blade loop, I am generating links. Inside link I got vue click event, when clicked, it opens a modal with form.

After I update record (with ajax), I am triggering `this.$emit('updateRoleName',response.name);`

It would be nice if I could update the link text, which was clicked, without any additional vm methods.

Any thoughts..., can this be done?

Comment: You can't apply the `@listen` event to the `anchor` element because it's not actually the `parent` of the `child` that performs `this.$emit()`. You would need to a tad bit of refactoring to support this.

Comment: You could add an event listener for `'updateRoleName'` like so: `this.$on('updateRoleName', name => this.role.name = name);`. But why not just call a method instead of emitting an `updateRoleName` event?

Comment: @thanksd, I am just looking for cleanest/simplest way to update the `$role->name`. Also, currently the link is php generated, not sure how could i connect it to vue? I would like to have the php generatation, so I can check roles & permissions before link has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

Fallowing suggestions, I stopped at this solution. Not the best, but kind of works.

So in Laravel blade I am generating link, here I can also do the roles/permission check:

```
<th>
    @can('edit role') <role-name-link :role="{{$role}}" /> @endcan
</th>
```

Inside `<role-name-link />`

```
<template>
    <a href="#" @click="open" @updateRoleName="updateName">{{name}}</a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['role'],
        name: "RoleNameLink",
        data() {
            return {
                name: this.role.name
            }
        },
        methods: {
            open(){
                Event.fire('openCrudRoleModal',this.role);
            },
            updateName(e){
                this.name = e.name;

            }
        },
        created() {
            Event.listen('updateRoleName', (role) =>{
                if(this.role.id == role.id) this.name = role.name;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Once link is clicked on, it will open a modal with update form. After update is completed it will $emit (Event.fire()) another event to update link text.

```
onSubmit(){
    this.spinner = this.form.processing;
    this.form[this.action]('/admin/roles/')
        .then(response => {
            this.$toastr.s('Role '+this.actionName[this.action]);
            if(this.action == 'patch') Event.fire('updateRoleName',response);
            this.hide();
        });
}
```

Back inside `<role-name-link />`, I still need to compare id's `if(this.role.id == role.id) this.name = role.name;`, else it will update all `names` in the table.

This will update the name in the php generated table. One gotcha there is, if I click the same link again, inside form it will show me the original name that was echoed by php.

Any thoughts, suggestions. How to make it better.... more elegant?